# TypeScript Discriminated Union Type with default and type inference

Tags: typescript, generics, unions, discriminated-union

I want to create a Discriminated Union Type, where it isn't required to pass the discriminator value.

Here's my current code:

```
interface Single<T> {
  multiple?: false // this is optional, because it should be the default
  value: T
  onValueChange: (value: T) => void
}

interface Multi<T> {
  multiple: true
  value: T[]
  onValueChange: (value: T[]) => void
}

type Union<T> = Single<T> | Multi<T>
```

For testing I use this:

```
function typeIt<T>(data: Union<T>): Union<T> {
    return data;
}

const a = typeIt({ // should be Single<string>
    value: "foo",
    onValueChange: (value) => undefined // why value is of type any?
})

const b = typeIt({ // should be Single<string>
    multiple: false,
    value: "foo",
    onValueChange: (value) => undefined
})

const c = typeIt({ // should be Multi<string>
    multiple: true,
    value: ["foo"],
    onValueChange: (value) => undefined
})
```

But I get a bunch of errors and warnings...:

1. In `const a`'s `onValueChange` the type of the parameter `value` is `any`. When setting `multiple: false` explicitly (like in `const b`) it gets correctly inferred as `string`.
2. `const c` doesn't work at all. I get this error: *"Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'"*.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

I've created a [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Single%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20multiple%3F%3A%20false%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20T%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onValueChange%3A%20(value%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Multi%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20multiple%3A%20true%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20T%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onValueChange%3A%20(value%3A%20T%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Union%3CT%3E%20%3D%20Single%3CT%3E%20%7C%20Multi%3CT%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20typeIt%3CT%3E(data%3A%20Union%3CT%3E)%3A%20Union%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20data%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20typeIt(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onValueChange%3A%20(value)%20%3D%3E%20undefined%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20typeIt(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20multiple%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onValueChange%3A%20(value)%20%3D%3E%20undefined%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20c%20%3D%20typeIt(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20multiple%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20%5B%22foo%22%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onValueChange%3A%20(value)%20%3D%3E%20undefined%0D%0A%7D)) with this code

Comment: If you are using generic types, then you should specify the type, it also helps other developers.

Comment: @Pavlo I could not disagree more. The power of TS is the ability to infer types (and I have inferred some highly complex types). Plus explicitly specifying the type basically duplicates the information which can be especially painful if the type is not explicitly named

Comment: It may be worth noting that 1 is documented [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41759) and 2 is fixed in version 3.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the compiler can easily infer the type of the `value` parameter in the callback since the type of the object literal is still not determined when the callback is checked.

If you don't have a lot of union members a solution that works as expected is to use multiple overloads:

```
export interface Single<T> {
  multiple?: false // this is optional, because it should be the default
  value: T
  onValueChange: (value: T) => void
}

interface Multi<T> {
  multiple: true
  value: T[]
  onValueChange: (value: T[]) => void
}

type Union<T> = Single<T> | Multi<T>

function typeIt<T>(data: Single<T>): Single<T>
function typeIt<T>(data: Multi<T>): Multi<T>
function typeIt<T>(data: Union<T>): Union<T> {
    return data;
}

const a = typeIt({ // is Single<string>
    value: "foo",
    onValueChange: (value) => undefined // value is typed as expected
})

const b = typeIt({ // is Single<string>
    multiple: false,
    value: "foo",
    onValueChange: (value) => undefined
})

const c = typeIt({ // is be Multi<string>
    multiple: true,
    value: ["foo"],
    onValueChange: (value) => undefined
})
```

Comment: Thank you. Works great!